# How to add different type of markers in Gmaps4Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I need to show two different markers in my Google map. I am using rails 3 and Gmaps4rails gem.

I my controller I have

```
 @marker1 = User.find(1)
 @marker2 = User.find(2)
 @json = [@marker1,@marker2].to_gmaps4rails
```

In view file

```
 <%= gmaps({
        "map_options" => { "zoom" => 12, "auto_adjust" => false, "center_latitude" => @marker1.lat, "center_longitude" => @marker1.lng},
        "markers"     => { "data" => @json }
        })
  %>

 <%= yield :scripts %>
```

The map view I get is

[image]

I need to add different marker images for the each of them. How can this be done. please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have simply one answer: it's explained in the [wiki](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Markers), within the `Customize each marker` section.

There is also some alternative to add the styles in a block from your controller instead of model level.

Comment: I have same problem, can you share solution?